# NGRX Angular service - getter use createdSelector

Tags: angular, ngrx

I would like to have a service where I can get ngrx selectors. Is good practice use createSelector directly in select?

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoginSelector{

    get data$() {
        return this.store.pipe(
            select(<b>createSelector</b>(
                this.loginState,
                function (state) {
                    return state && state.data;
                }
            ))
        );
    }

    constructor(
        protected storeActions$: Actions,
        protected store: Store<StoreState>,
    ) {}
}
```

Maybe not because createSelector retrun always new MemoizedSelector

```js
const selectData = <b>createSelector</b>(
  this.loginState,
  function (state) {
    return state && state.data;
  }
);

@Injectable()
export class LoginSelector{

  get data$() {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(selectData)
    );
  }

  constructor(
    protected storeActions$: Actions,
    protected store: Store<StoreState>,
  ) {}
}
```

Thank you.